# How to slice pandas data frame based on a categorical variable - ei Country

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a simple line graph that illustrates the change in CO2 Emissions over time, for the countries with the top 10 GDP.

I'm a bit new with python and pandas, and while I figured out the following way to do it -- by slicing the main df and creating smaller data frames for each country, I know there is a simpler way to do this, I just can't quite figure out a more efficient way to slice the data and assign the necessary variables to have all lines represented on 1 chart.

Data link (csv) -- https://www.kaggle.com/yoannboyere/co2-ghg-emissionsdata

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import rcParams
import seaborn as sb


# Importing the dataset
df = pd.read_csv('co2_emission.csv')

df_China= df.loc[df['Entity'] == 'China']
X2 = df_China.iloc[:,2]
y2 = df_China.iloc[:,3]

df_Japan=df.loc[df['Entity']=='Japan']
X3 = df_Japan.iloc[:,2]
y3 = df_Japan.iloc[:,3]

plt.plot(X2,y2, label='China')
plt.plot(X3,y3, label='Japan')

plt.legend()
plt.title('CO2 Emissions of Nations with the Top 10 GDP')
sb.set_style(style='darkgrid')
plt.show()
```

[image: Example of what I'd like to create (but with 8 added lines)]

Comment: Is it possible for you to share `'co2_emission.csv'`?

Comment: Finally, I used my own dataset but it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are importing seaborn, in this case you can use it to make the things easier:

```
df = pd.read_csv('co2_emission.csv')
sns.lineplot(data=df, hue='Entity', y='Annual CO₂ emissions (tonnes )', x='Year')
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the data you sent since `co2_emission.csv` was not provided, therefore the graphs will looks a little weird.

Anyways, the main difference in my code is the usage of `set_index` in order to plot by `Year` for the x-axis, and of course the `groupby` which uses to group the entities into their own groups (and subplots).

Here's the code:

```
import pandas as pd    

# Importing the dataset
df = pd.read_csv('co2_emission.csv')

# Plotting annual emission per entity, by year
df.set_index('Year').groupby('Entity')['Annual CO₂ emissions (tonnes )'].plot(legend=True)
```

[image: The graph looks a little weird because of the data, try it with real data and it should be good.]

If you have any further questions feel free to ask.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As a quick follow up, I'm curious how to use groupby to be more specific, and instead of just using 'Entity', but also selecting specific features within that column - in this case - specific countries. I also added a link to the dataset.

Comment: If you just wish to filter by specific countries, you can always slice the dataframe before grouping, i.e `china_japan_df = df[np.logical_or(df['Entity'] == 'Japan', df['Entity'] == 'China')]` and then simply use the command from the answer on `china_japan_df`

Answer (score 0):

For my answer, I used the [CO2 emissions (kt)](https://data.worldbank.org/indicator/EN.ATM.CO2E.KT)  from The World Bank and I converted to a similar structure than you:

```
df = pd.read_csv('API_EN.ATM.CO2E.KT_DS2_en_csv_v2_2445474.csv', skiprows=4)
df = df.drop(columns=['Indicator Name', 'Indicator Code'])
df = df.set_index(['Country Name', 'Country Code'])
df = df.rename_axis(columns='Year', index=['Entity', 'Code']).stack() \
       .rename('CO₂ emissions (tonnes)').reset_index().astype({'Year': int})
```

```
>>> df
         Entity Code  Year  CO₂ emissions (tonnes)
0         Aruba  ABW  1960               11092.675
1         Aruba  ABW  1961               11576.719
2         Aruba  ABW  1962               12713.489
3         Aruba  ABW  1963               12178.107
4         Aruba  ABW  1964               11840.743
...         ...  ...   ...                     ...
12983  Zimbabwe  ZWE  2012                7873.049
12984  Zimbabwe  ZWE  2013               11771.070
12985  Zimbabwe  ZWE  2014               12115.768
12986  Zimbabwe  ZWE  2015               12317.453
12987  Zimbabwe  ZWE  2016               10982.665

[12988 rows x 4 columns]
```

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.set_style(style='darkgrid')

gdp10 = ['United States', 'China', 'Japan', 'Germany', 'United Kingdom',
         'France', 'India', 'Italy', 'Brazil', 'Canada']
df10 = df.loc[df['Entity'].isin(gdp10)].set_index('Entity').loc[gdp10].reset_index()

ax = sns.lineplot(data=df10, hue='Entity', y='CO₂ emissions (tonnes)', x='Year')
ax.set_title('CO2 Emissions of Nations with the Top 10 GDP')
```

[image: CO2 Emissions]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm curious how the top 10 gdp countries were chosen in this code. I see the [gdp10], but am not putting all the pieces together. Any clarification would be great, thanks!

Comment: Sorry :-P I forgot the variable `gdp10`. My list is probably not up to date, especially for India.

Comment: Lastest list from WB: https://databank.worldbank.org/data/download/GDP.pdf